# Relationship between eigenvalues of summation of two matrices one is diagonal

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I wonder if someone can prove/disprove the following inequality,

$\lambda_i(A+mI) \leq \lambda_i(A+K) \leq \lambda_i(A+MI)$

where $A$ is a real symmetric Metzler matrix with real and nonpositive eigenvalues and $K$ is a diagonal matrix. $M$ and $m$ are the greatest and the least elements of $K$ respectively.

I have seen that the above inequality holds for all examples I tried but I would like to prove it mathematically or find a counterexample.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What us a "Metzler matrix"?

Comment: Saw it already; thanks.  Cheers!

Comment: So do you know the answer?

Comment: Well, sort of.  I have a question:  what does $\lambda_i(A + mI)$ etc. mean, exactly?